# Logic Sign Puzzle

Tags: pattern

"Bad" Design is on purpose. Your task is to fill the two empty spaces with the correct sign. Edit: I'm sorry if it's too hard

[image: The Puzzle]

Comment: In row 5 column 1 there is a pixel with color $(191, 191, 191)$, and in row 5 column 2 there is a pixel with color $(223, 223, 223)$. Are these also intentional?

Comment: @WhatsUp  that's my fault, has no meaning

Comment: Hi square root it has been a while since you asked... can we have a hint?

Comment: @Deepthinker101 it's about numbers

Comment: I think the fact that they are Roman numerals is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 3):

This is by no means an answer, but here is one thing that I've noticed:

> There appears to be a series of "L"s forming the shape of an "L", which makes me think that empty space needs an "L":
>
> [image]

That will also explain the "bad" design

> because if the "bad" design weren't there, it would be to easy to make out that pattern.